# Excel doesn't show all data (Only last cell of one column and some strange values)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am selecting both columns to create Bar chart but excel is selecting only last value of column for one axis. Also values are getting converted into some strange numbers. This is happening for all kind of data. I want to create simple Bar chart for two columns. Please see screenshot. I have selected both complete columns but after making chart, only last cell is selected... What is this???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a histogram chart, but the data is not set up for this and you probably wanted a regular column chart, anyway.

If you want to have dates on the X axis, the easiest way is to remove the heading for that column before creating the chart. So, in your case:

- remove the text in cell C7
- click any cell in the range C8 to D26
- click Insert > Select a column chart (not a histogram)
- now you can put the words back int cell C7

[image]

If your chart still doesn't look right, you may want to ensure that the values in column D are really numbers and not text.

If there is a label above the column of dates, Excel will interpret this as a series. By removing the label, you enable Excel to recognize this range as the X categories.

Comment: Thanks a lo!!! Actually, I had text in my numbers and that is why it was happening.